# C++ UNIX: Threading: Make Main-Thread wait or sleep until processing is over - main-thread doesnt know pthread_t refrences

Tags: c++, multithreading, unix, pthreads

sc->start_server runs an endless loop in which a MyClass processing method is invoked in a thread.
How can i replace the while(true) statement in main so that my program waits for all threads to terminate?

EDIT: pthreads-lib is used and main() does not know the pthread_t references

THX

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {

            SocketCommunication * sc = SocketCommunication::get_menu();  //Singleton

            MyClass yay;       
            short port = 6644;

            sc->start_server(port, &yay);

            while(true);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What threading library are you using? pthreads?

Comment: yes i use pthreads, but main() does not know the pthread_t references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `join` on any thread you want to wait.

Comment: Maybe the SocketCommunication class does ? Make a method in it that wait for the associated thread to terminate.

Comment: No it does not know it too, its in a other layer which is more down in the architecture

Comment: It should know about it. We gave you the proper way to do what you want. If you can't do it, that probably means there is something wrong in your architecture.

Comment: theres nothing wrong in the architecture, sc is a lib which starts threads for listener servers. it starts several threads on which main() has to wait without knowing them

Answer (score 3):

The usual way (in pthreads, at least) is:

1. You have several `pthread_t` references to running threads.
2. Instead of your `while` loop at the end, you wait for all of them to finish with something similar to `pthread_join(threadX, NULL);`, for all the threads.

In your case, I don't see any API to get the threads, but once you get hold of the threads running (maybe asking `sc` in some way), the code would be similar.

**EDIT**:

If you just want to wait for a condition, it is easy with condition variables. Supposing you have available these:

```
pthread_mutex_t end_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  condition_var = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
bool all_threads_done = false; // Signals that all the threads are finalized
```

Then, in your `main()` you can wait for it with:

```
pthread_mutex_lock( &end_mutex );
while (!all_threads_done) 
    pthread_cond_wait( &condition_var, &end_mutex );
```

The `wait` will release the mutex while waiting. Then, on each thread, you have to have the following:

```
// Do whatever the thread has to do...
// ...
// and then, at the end...
pthread_mutex_lock( &end_mutex );
if (no_more_threads()) // You have to figure this thing out to ensure no more threads
    all_threads_done = true;
pthread_cond_signal( &condition_var );
pthread_mutex_unlock( &end_mutex );
```

Note, finally, that, even when you're doing a `while`, it is not a busy waiting, as most of the time the main thread is waiting in `pthread_cond_wait`, and is awakened just when any of the threads ends.

Comment: main does not know the pthread_t references, so what about waiting for a signal if a thread terminates and main catches that signal - is that possible or do you have a better solution??

Comment: Well sc doesnt know the refrences too - they are in way more down layer so i think signal emmit would be fine - or do you have another tipp??